# How to set equivalent of fetch's { credentials: "include" } in Redux Toolkit's createApi?

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js, rtk-query

I have an express-react-typescript-redux-passport project where I am using `createApi` from redux toolkit to call a `/getuser` api on my backend.

I'm using `passport-google-oauth20` strategy to authenticate users, and the user is successfully authenticated.

My issue is that passport js `deserializeUser()` function is not called (even though the `serializeUser()` is called, and the user is authenticated using google strategy), so the `req.user` parameter is not set automatically when the front end sends requests to the back end.

I *suspect* that `deserializeUser` isn't being called because the I haven't set axio's `{ withCredentials: true }` (or fetch's `{credentials: "include"}`) parameter in my `createApi` endpoint. How can I sent this parameter in RTK's createApi?

**How do I specify credentials: include here?**

Here is my createApi function

```js
export const userApiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:4000",
    prepareHeaders(headers) {
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints(builder) {
    // debugger;
    return {
      fetchUser: builder.query<IUser, number | void>({
        query: () => {
          debugger;
          return `/getuser`;
        },
      }),
    };
  },
});
```

Here is my server index.js

```js
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import session from "express-session";
import passport from "passport";

var GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
import { IGoogleAuthUser } from "./types/authTypes";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();

mongoose.connect(process.env.LOCAL_DB_ADDRESS, () => {
  console.log("connected to mongoose db");
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser((user: IGoogleAuthUser, done: any) => {
  //send a cookie to browser to store user id in session
  const { id} = user;
  console.log("serializeUser called");
  return done(null, id);
});

// why isn't this called???
passport.deserializeUser((userId: string, done: any) => {
  //attaches the cookie id from session to req.user
  console.log("deserializeUser userId : ", userId);
  return done(null, userId);
});

//google strategy
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
    },
    function (accessToken: any, refreshToken: any, profile: any, done: any) {
      //this is called on succesful authentication with the above Google Stratety     
      console.log("successful authorization");
      done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

//when user clicks on 'login with google' /auth/google is hit
app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] }),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log("/auth/google called"); //this console.log does not get called, not sure why
  }
);

app.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/profile",
    failureRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/login",
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    // console.dir(req);
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    console.log("redirect to profile"); //this does get called
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/profile"); 
  }
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world.");
});

app.get("/getuser", (req: any, res: any) => {
  //req should have user thanks to serializer/deserializer
  console.log(req.user); // => returns undefined even after successful authentication
  res.send(req.user);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server Started on ${PORT}`);
});
```

**Why isn't `deserializeUser()` being called??**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`fetchBaseQuery` is just a wrapper around `fetch` with some extra options.

So it's either

```js
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:4000",
    prepareHeaders(headers) {
      return headers;
    },
    credentials: "include"
  }),
```

or

```js
        query: () => {
          return { url: `/getuser`, credentials: "include" };
        },
```

Comment: I was encountering a similar issue where my NestJS API was not delivering a session cookie to the browser hosting my React app frontend. This answer unblocked me, thanks!